# Calculating UI rendering time or draw time for iOS Native application

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to iOS development . I am trying to calculate the UI draw time for a particular screen in my iOS application. Please help me to measure the UI draw or rendering time of the application .

I have tried profiling tools available in instruments , but it is not providing the exact value.

Thanks In Advance !

Answer (score 0):

Wihtout using tools,

```
-(void)draw{
    NSLog(@"Start Time:%@",[NSDate date]);
    //Some functions
    NSLog(@"End Time:%@",[NSDate date]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vichevstefan , For example  Lets take that I am navigating to settings screen of my app on the click of a button , Where should I implement this code ? or if i want to get the time for every screen of my application what should I do ?  Thanks In Advance

Comment: what about using start at button Action, and end at viewDidAppear?

Comment: Thanks Vichevstefan , Lemme try.

Comment: Do we still have any tools to find out UI rendering time other than instruments ?